# A buffer overflow attack on Windows results in access violation

Tags: c, security, shellcode

I just started looking into how [buffer overflow](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) attacks work, and tried simulating an attack on **Windows 7** using Visual C 2010. The buffer overflow attack is very contrived, it just overwrites the return address to the address of the "buffer" local variable. The buffer holds the string of shellcode.

Whether I run the program in Visual Studio 2010 Debug or not, the program will *jump to the shellcode* and almost begins execution of it, but I get an Access Violation error, and the program will not continue executing the shellcode.

Why am I getting this error? Is this some sort of protection against buffer overflows in Windows?

How would *you* get the program to execute the shellcode in the buffer?

*edit:*

Hans (answer) is correct. This is discussed within the Security chapter of Windows Internals 5th, and the cause of the error is Microsoft's implementation of [Executable Space Protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Executable_space_protection).

If this question helped anyone, any up-votes would be appreciated.

```
void execute_my_shellcode()
{
    char buffer[24];
    memcpy(buffer, "\x6A\x21\xFF\x15\x40\x62\x40\x00\x83\xC4\x04\x6A\x0A\xFF\x15\x40\x62\x40\x00\x83\xC4\x04\xC3", 24); 
    printf("current return address: %p\n", *(int*)((char*)&buffer + 24 + 4));   
    *(int*)((char*)&buffer + 24 + 4) = (int)&buffer; 
    printf("return address is now : %p\n\n", (int*)*(int*)((char*)&buffer + 24 + 4) );
}
```

Comment: Once you get around the NX issue, can you do me a favor and post what happens when you run the executable with ASLR enabled on the executable itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might have worked 10 years ago.  These obvious security holes have been patched, the [no-execute bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) that processors support nowadays are one of the counter-measure.

Comment: No, thay have not been patched, they have been worked-around.

Comment: Erm, yeah, C arrays will be broken forever.

Comment: Hans, so which form of protection is in use when I receive this Access Violation exception (in Visual Studio Debug mode)? Is it the no-execute bit, or something else? Is this Windows-specific?

Comment: You are asking for details that only somebody that sits 3 feet in front of your machine could really answer.  I don't even know what Windows version you use.  Not sure why it matters, isn't the NX bit enough?

Comment: NX bit is certainly helpful to me, but I don't know if that's the answer for this case, and I'm just looking for which form of protection might be in use for this situation, for the purposes of understanding, not to test the knowledge of the SO community. I'm using Windows 7, the program is compiled to Win32 platform.

Comment: This is the answer to your question.  Find understanding in "Windows Internals" 5th edition, excellent book.

Comment: Your insight is appreciated as always Hans. Hopefully I'll soon be able to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

There are other protections in place against Buffer Overflow attacks that might make this impossible, such as Guard Pages at each begin and end of the stack frame.  There is the Address Space Layout Randomization and others.  [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) is an article on this.

The fact is also that your shellcode could be containing nullbytes or other types of invalid char's which when converted don't turn into an instruction or valid address...  That is for you to figure out.

*note* I am not giving this latter advice to be abused. You are *responsible* for **legally** and correctly using this advice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your shellcode has nulls in it.  Go back through your shellcode and find instructions that don't produce null opcodes (0x00) so that your shellcode doesn't get treated as a string.

Second, an access violation doesn't necessarily mean it's the cause of some type of protection scheme.  It may be (out of whim) that your return address or shellcode is trying to make the the EIP register jump to a place that can't be executed in memory.

You will have to expirement more.  Each compiler and computer is going to be different.  There are ways around just about everything.  You may want to research more on the topic in general but the first thing I would suggest is creating a repeating return address that points to a NOP sled in the buffer before the shellcode so that your shellcode get's executed more efficiently and is likely to be more accurate.

The Executable Space Protection is correct, as you stated, but my answers above are both informal and necessary in most cases.  Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is the program breaking? Have you tried using [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) to step through the assembly instructions to see if you are at least starting execution of the buffer or failing before then? If you're not executing even the first instruction in the buffer, then likely the stack page (or data section in this case since you supply it as a string literal) has been marked non-executable and you'll have to use another technique. There might be a way to tell Windows to make the stack page executable (or data section in this case) for testing/learning purposes (I know ELF binaries have an executable stack flag and Linux provides the `execstack` utility to edit the flag).

If it's breaking after several instructions from your buffer, then it's likely because the instructions in your buffer are trying to (indirectly) call an absolute address (`0xff 0x15 0x40 0x62 0x40 x00` => `call dword ptr ds:[406240]`) and in W7, [address space layout randomization](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (ASLR) may be enabled (I'm not sure if the VS2010 linker sets the IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE bit in the PE header by default).

**Edit**

Based on the additional info you've added to the question, it would appear that the issue of a non-executable stack, mentioned in my first paragraph is the culprit. However, even if you get around that the second issue may still be an issue as you have no clue what will be at 0x00406240 if ASLR is enabled.

Comment: I've added a "clarification edit" in the question which might help.

Comment: @T. Webster One last clarification then: the very first instruction (0x6a 0x21 => `push 21`) is failing? Also this code will not properly call `puts`, assuming that 0x00406240 is the proper address in the import address table for `puts`. `puts` takes a single `char*` argument, which you provide first as `0x21` and the second time as `0x0a`. This means that `puts` will try to output the string located at memory address 0x00000021. Probably what you want is `putchar` which takes a single 32-bit character instead of a `char*`?

Comment: ah right, I meant putchar. 0x21 is the char '!'. Your response is helpful, so I've upvoted.

Comment: address space layout randomization (ASLR) doesn't seem like it's the issue here. I am directly storing the address value of buffer[] into the stack's return address location.

Comment: -1 He is getting actual address of `&buffer` thus ASLR has no effect in this situation.

Comment: @Rook He is in fact getting the address of `&buffer`, but there's other factors coming into play. If ASLR is enabled, then the image base address can move as well, which will cause both functions in the executable and also entries in the IAT to move. Including a hardcoded address to the IAT (or another function in the executable which I thought was the case at the time) will then cause access violations the majority of the time.

Comment: @user470379 shellcode is meant to be address independent,  you just have to find it in memory.  But oah look we have: `&buffer`, problem solved.

Comment: @Rook "shellcode is meant to be address independent". That's exactly the point!!! Disassemble the code from the beginning -- ["\x6A\x21" => `push 21`; "\xFF\x15\x40\x62\x40\x00" => `call [00406240]`] and so on. `call [00406240]` is __NOT__ address independent. It assumes that the IAT is always in the same spot which is __NOT__ the case with ASLR. This code __will__ fail _even if_ the stack page is marked executable when ASLR is enabled for the application (unless you get lucky). This is not generically designed shellcode, either OP wrote it or grabbed a non-generic example from a tutorial.

Comment: @Rook I'm not disputing the fact whether or not OP is finding the beginning of the shellcode. He obviously is. The problem is that _the shellcode_ references absolute addresses. Once OP executes the second instruction in the address space of an executable with ASLR enabled, all bets are off.